# Deserialization of key value pair in XML to c# object

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization

I have XML as shown below.

```
 <Device-array>
   <Device>
    <id>8</id>
    <properties>
     <PropKeyValuePair>...</PropKeyValuePair>
     <PropKeyValuePair>...</PropKeyValuePair>
    </properties>
   </Device>
   <Device>...</Device>
   <Device>...</Device>
 </Device-array>
```

I am planning to deserialize it to C# object so that it will be faster. I only require the id field. But i understand that the class need to have an array for (properties). But how do i represent the key valuepair ?

```
[Serializable()]
public class SLVGeoZone
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public string id { get; set; } 

    //Arraylist of key value pairs here ?

 }
```

need suggetions.

Comment: If you only need ID, why are you adding the keyvaluepairs to the class? I'm pretty sure that tags you don't reference will be ignored when deserializing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to XML instead of deserialization and get just what you need: list of ids:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("FilePath.xml");

var ids = xDoc.Root
              .Elements("Device")
              .Select(x => (int)x.Element("id"))
              .ToList();
```

If you really need to use deserialization you can just omit properties you don't need and `XmlSerializer` will deserialize just declared content, skipping elements you didn't declare in your class.

**Update**

To get more then just a name into list of anonymous type:

```
var ids = xDoc.Root
              .Elements("Device")
              .Select(x => new {
                  Id =  (int)x.Element("id"),
                  Name = (string)x.Element("name")
              })
              .ToList();
```

Comment: Lets say i have array of 500 devices and i need only ids in each of them. Whether LINQ is better in terms of performance then ?

Comment: I don't know. You have to measure it. It's definitely more readable and easy to use, because you don't have to declare any class and code is really straightforward.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the reply. Suppose there is one more Element "Name". Can i get the list of id and respective name from Linq query ?

Comment: Sure. You can use anonymous type to get the without additional classes.